# Subgroups of (Z,*) = x*y=x+y+ 3

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have some doubts: the subgroups in (Z, +) are of the form nZ, but if I wanted to find for example the subgroup generated by 5 in (Z, *) how should I do? x * x = x + x + 3 x ^ n = nx + 5 (n - 1) thank you so much

Comment: Your question is not clear,,,can you define clearly,,,* operation,,,,is it multiplication?

Comment: This group of yours is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ under the isomorphism $ x\mapsto x-3$. The number $5$ maps to 2. The cyclic subgroup generared by $2$ is the group of all even numbers. So the subgroup of your group generated by $5$ consists of all numbers $2n+3$, i.e., of all odd numbers.

Comment: Sorry it should be $+3$: $f(x*y)=f(x+y+3) = x+y+6=f(x)+f(y)$. The answer is the same, though.

Comment: @JCAA so multiples of 5 have the form $8n-3$ not $2n+3$.

Comment: No. 5 goes to 8. The sub generated by 8 consists of numbers $8n$, mapping it back gives numbers of the form $8n-3$ or, same, $8n+5$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the map $(\mathbb{Z},*)\to (\mathbb{Z},+)$ sending $x\mapsto x+3$.  Is it a bijection?  Is it a homomorphism?  If it is both, then they are the same group, so you can just take the subgroups of $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ and map them back to $(\mathbb{Z},*)$, to find the subgroups of $(\mathbb{Z},*)$.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. Can you show me the computation that proves $x \mapsto x + 3$ is a homomorphism?

Comment: @CharlesHudgins what you want to check is $f(x * y)=f(x) + f(y)$

Comment: Thanks so much for the clarifications.
So starting from the map  $(\mathbb{Z},+)\to (\mathbb{Z},*)$ sending $x\mapsto x-3$ I find the subgroups in $(\mathbb{Z},*)$.
For example let's take the subgroup 5Z of (Z,+), in $(\mathbb{Z},*)$ 
we'll have

$0\mapsto 0-3$,
$5\mapsto 5-3$,
$10\mapsto 10-3$,
...............
$-5\mapsto -5-3$
and so on

Comment: Yes that is exactly how you get the subgroups.

Comment: Without using isomorphism how can you do it?

Comment: When asked to identify the subgroups of a group the first instinct is to understand the group.  In this case it turns out to be something familiar and the problem is easily solved.  You could instead note that your group is freely generated by -2, so subgroups are generated by elements of the form $-2*-2*\cdots*-2$.  However you are still effectively constructing an isomorphism to $(\mathbb{Z},+)$.

Comment: Therefore, being 5 equal to  2..from the map (Z,+)→(Z,∗) sending x↦x−3, and being  2∗2∗⋯∗2=
 2 ^ n = n2 + 3 (n-1) $ for each x, n belonging to Z, the lists of our subgroup can be obtained from n2 + 3 (n-1)

Comment: The generator is -2, not 2, so using your method, you get the generators of subgroups to be $-2n+3(n-1)=n-3$ for $n=0,1,2,3,\cdots$, which is the sequence $-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,\cdots$.  Each of these generate a different subgroup, and every subgroup is of this form.  Note the subgroup generated by -3 is the trivial group, whilst the rest are all isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z},+)$.

Comment: I got confused, with my method I meant the list of elements of the subgroup generated by 2, which in (Z, +) corresponds to that generated by 5 For example, since -2 is a generator of the group (Z, ∗), with -2n +3 (n-1) I find all its lists                                                                                Am I right! Thanks so much

Comment: Yes 2 generates a subgroup containing all numbers of the form $2n+3(n-1)=5n-3$.  Also you are right that -2 generates numbers of the form $-2n+3(n-1)=n-3$ which is the whole group.